# Remove HTML element based on innerHTML

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make this Google Chrome extension that runs in the background only and the end user doesn't need to interact with it, no need to click any options. Suppose there is an element like the following in a web page.

```
<tr>
    <td class="chart">
       <a>Intel Xeon Silver 4123 @ 3.00GHz</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

When the user visits this webpage the extension should automatically remove the entire < t r > element. My code is as follows but it's not working.

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName('chart').innerHTML.contains('Xeon')) {
    document.getElementByClassName('chart').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: can't you just set `id` of the element you want to remove?

Comment: the code `document.getElementsByClassName('chart')` returns an `HTMLCollection[]` not a `DOMElement`. You'll have to loop over every element in the array i.e.: `document.getElementsByClassName('chart')[0].innerHTML.contains('Xeon')`.

Comment: Still isn't working.

Comment: Before you use the code in an extension, you should probably check it works either in the browser console, or save the webpage then add your own JavaScript to the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code `document.getElementsByClassName('chart')` returns an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) not a DOM [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element). You'll have to loop over every element in the array i.e.:

```
var charts = document.getElementsByClassName('chart');
if(charts.length) {
    for(var i=0; i<charts.length; i++) {
        if(charts[i].tagName === 'TD' && charts[i].innerHTML.includes('Xeon')) {
            charts[i].parentNode.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
```

also note:

- it's [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName) (elements plural) not `getElementByClassName()` (singular).
- it's [`String.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) not `String.contains()`
- and you probably want to use [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode) to hide the entire row

Comment: does this have to go in content.js or background.js for google chrome extension? i tried putting the code in both files, but it's not doing anything.

Comment: it's `String.includes()` not `String.contains()`

Comment: It seems like it's getting rid of all the rows instead of matching the ones with "Xeon"

Comment: The 1st match is the `<table class="chart">` so you're code replaces the whole thing on the 1st match

Comment: starting the for loop from var i=1 does the trick. btw, thanks a lot for this. all is working greatly.

Comment: I modified the answer to include `charts[i].tagName === 'TD'` to only manipulate table cells. Which is better than `var i=1`. Imagine tomorrow the table has a `tbody class="chart"`, the content would be wiped out again. And do you know about  [TamperMonkey](https://tampermonkey.net/) / [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184274/discussion-between-noobcoder-and-djdavemark).